# Networking "popup menu" not showing correct behavior

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

I have an annoying problem that appeared after I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04. I have read many other topics where people have different issues with wireless on 16.04 but they don't seem to be as bizarre as mine (and their solutions are not working). Essentially, what is shown in the networking "popup menu" is not correlated to whether or not my wireless is working. For instance, right now, my menu looks like this:

[image]

and my computer is automatically connected to my wifi (because my internet is working), but I can not see this or any other available wireless networks. However, my menu has also looked like this:

[image]

and my computer was still connected automatically to my wifi! It has also looked like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

One of the last two were taken when the wifi was not working, don't remember which one though, but that is not very important since the main issue is that I can not see available networks in any of the cases. Sometimes my wifi also stops working randomly, and I then restart using the command

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

This usually works (but not always), but it usually does not solve the issue with the menu showing incorrect info. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Some extra information:

the command

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

gives

```
*-network               
description: Ethernet interface
product: Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 19
bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
logical name: eth0
version: 03
serial: f8:ca:b8:5c:90:84
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.2-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:51 memory:f7200000-f721ffff memory:f7243000-f7243fff ioport:f080(size=32)
*-network
description: Wireless interface
product: Wireless 7265
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: wlan0
version: 59
serial: 10:02:b5:7c:84:13
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-93-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.0.18 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
 resources: irq:50 memory:f7000000-f7001fff
```

the command

```
 rfkill list all
```

gives

```
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
14: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

the command

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

gives

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

the command

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

gives

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Update:
Now my menu has taken on yet another appearance:

[image]

and it is still automatically connected to my wireless network with working internet...

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and also: `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and also: `rfkill list all`.

Comment: Ok I have added this info.